# Confidence Intervals for the coefficients of a Multiple Multivariate Regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, multivariate-regression

I have a functional response [ *y(t)* ] that I have discretized on a grid of *q* points, and 3 scalar regressors (x1,x2,x3). I have replaced the response function with an *nxq* matrix **Y** and this lead me to a Multiple Multivariate Regression problem:

**Y = XB + E**

where **X** [*nxp* ] is x1,x2,x3 column-stacked, **B** is a *p×q* matrix of regression coefficients and **E** is an *n×q* matrix of errors. Indeed, what I have done is to call `lm(Y ~ X)` in R.

I couldn't find much material online about the computation of the confidence intervals for the coefficients *β1(t)*, *β2(t)* and *β3(t)* ( **B** = [*β1(t)*,*β2(t)*,*β3(t)*] )  .

The only idea I came up with is to compute point-wise confidence intervals, on the grid of *q* points. Is that the right approach, there are other methods?

Thank you in advance

-- EDIT --

In my problem, I can assume the *n* observations of y(t) independent.

I am sure I don't have a problem of multicollinearity because the independent variables  x1,x2,x2 come from a selection from a PCA analysis.

About the response variables *y(t)*, these are positive function with first and second derivative strictly greater than zero and when I discretize them on a grid of 25 points I get this correlation matrix (a sort of tridiagonal matrix).

[image: Corr(Y)]

Comment: The `R` code might not be doing what you think: it merely conducts $nq$ separate ordinary regressions, one for each component of the response.  It does not attempt to estimate or account for interdependence among the response components.

Comment: Thank you for the remark. What should I use instead?

Comment: I don't know, because it depends on what assumptions you are making about the covariance structure of your response but you haven't written anything about that.

Comment: You can just use the ordinary confidence intervals unless you are interested in simultaneous intervals. Even there you can just use the ordinary intervals with Bonferroni critical values. If you want to be less conservative, you can stiull use the ordinary intervals, except with a critical value that incorporates the partial correlations of your $Y$ vector, e.g., Chapter 11 of "Multiple Comparisons and Multiple Tests Using SAS", (Peter H. Westfall, Randall D. Tobias, Russell D. Wolfinger).